# Vapor 3, Pre populate table with data from another table

Tags: swift, database, postgresql, vapor, vapor-fluent

I am trying to pre populate tables with Vapor 3 and Vapor fluent. I am new to Vapor

I'm trying to populate `Sharedkeys` with data from `Platform`. I have managed to query `Platform`. However, I am struggling to populate `SharedKeys`

So every `platform` will have a `shared key`

I have included an example below, with this I have no luck.

On this line
`let sharedKeys = platforms.map { platform in` 
I get an compile error 
`Unable to infer complex closure return type: add explicit type to disambiguate`

I then realised that `map` is returning `[T]`, can't figure out a way to create `Future<SharedKey>` instead of `[SharedKey]`

Here is an example of my coding, feel free to criticise!

Platform Model

```swift
struct Platform : Codable {
    var id : Int?
    /// Type of platform, i.e. iPhone, iPad, Android etc...
    var platform : String

    init(platform : String) {
        self.platform = platform
    }
}

extension Platform : PostgreSQLModel, Content {}
extension Platform : PostgreSQLMigration {

    static func prepare(on conn: PostgreSQLConnection) -> Future<Void> {
        return Database.create(self, on: conn) { builder in
            try addProperties(to: builder)
            builder.unique(on: \.platform)
        }
    }
}
```

SharedKey Model

```swift
final class SharedKey: Codable {
    var id : Int?
    /// platform
    var platID : Platform.ID?
    /// shared key
    var key : String

    init(key: String, platform : Platform) {
        self.key    = key
        self.platID = platform.id
    }
}

extension SharedKey : PostgreSQLModel, Content {}
extension SharedKey : PostgreSQLMigration {

    static func prepare(on conn: PostgreSQLConnection) -> Future<Void> {
        return Database.create(self, on: conn) { builder in
            try addProperties(to: builder)
            builder.unique(on: \.key)
        }
    }
}
```

Trying to populate `sharedKey`

```swift
        let p = Platform.query(on: conn).all()
        let keysFuture = p.flatMap(to: [SharedKey].self) { platforms in

            let sharedKeys = platforms.map { platform in
                let key = SharedKey(key: "<random key>", platform: platform)
                return key.save(on: conn)
            }

            return sharedKeys
        }
```

What I am expecting is the variable `keysFuture` to be type `Future<[SharedKey]>` NOT `[SharedKey]`

Edit:

I have used this example to pre populate `Platform`:
https://mihaelamj.github.io/Pre-populating%20a%20Database%20with%20Data%20in%20Vapor/

Populating strings into a table is easy but trying to populate `shared key` with `platform` is a challenge for me.

I realised that I need Sharedkeys to be `[EventLoopFuture<Void>]` 
I did updated the following:

```swift
   let pp = Platform.query(on: conn).all()
        let op = pp.map { platforms in

           return platforms.map { p in
                return SharedKey(key: "random", platform: p).create(on: conn).map(to: Void.self) { _ in return }
            }
        }
```

However, this returns as `EventLoopFutrue<[EventLoopFutrue<Void>]>` is there a way of unwrapping this?

I just need to append `[EventLoopFutrue<Void>]` to `futures` from the link above (https://mihaelamj.github.io)

Comment: I believe that the better way is to copy data between tables with just one raw sql query instead of huge iterations in Swift. Just google how to copy rows between tables with PostgreSQL 

Comment: If to speak about your way you need to return Future<Void> from map and then do flatten(on: req) on that array of futures.

Comment: Can you provide a code snippet with `Future<Void>` and `flatter(on:req)` I've tried looking on google for example, haven't come across an example that I need cheers

Comment: let user1 = User().create(on: req).transform(to: ()); let user2 = User().create(on: req).transform(to: ()); [user1, user2].flatten(on: req).map { print("done") }

Comment: Thank you for the example, tried to do something similar and I ended up doing this:

```swift
        let pp = Platform.query(on: conn).all()
        let op = pp.map { platforms in
            
            return platforms.map { p in
                return SharedKey(key: "random", platform: p).create(on: conn).map(to: Void.self) { _ in return }
            }
        }
```

however, its returning `EventLoopFuture<[EventLoopFuture<Void>]>` is there a way of unwrapping this to `[EventLoopFuture<Void>]` just an array of future void

Comment: This should work  `func test(on: req) throws -> Future<Void> { return Platform.query(on: conn).all().flatMap { platforms in return platforms.map { p in return SharedKey(key: "random", platform: p).create(on: conn).transform(to: ()) }}}`

Comment: Also you could find me in Discord as imike#3049